# Como fazer uma tarefa Cron com Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, cron

Tenho uma function em php/laravel, e gostaria de disparar essa function a cada 2 horas e 35 minutos.

Minha dúvida é: 
Usando Laravel, como eu crio de forma correta, um cron para disparar essa função nesse intervalo de tempo?

Comment: nao pq a de cima mostra como fazer de 24h eu quero saber como ficaria pra fazer de 2:35h em 2:35h e seguindo como mencionou aqui não deu certo @DarleiFernandoZillmer

Comment: É a mesma coisa, você só precisa definir os horarios que vai rodar, pode usar o twiceDaily(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...) para isso.

Comment: ah sim obrigado